# Equal values in column

Tags: awk

I would to check if all values are the same in column 2.

**If all values in column 2 are equal**, the output should be

```
2835:  OK
```

If column 2 has different value , the output should be

```
2835:  BAD
```

**Input file:**

```
2835:  BAD
2835:  OK
2835:  OK
2835:  BAD
2835:  OK
2835:  BAD
2835:  OK
2835:  OK
2835:  OK
```

**my code**

```
awk '{a[$2]++} END { for (n in a ) print $0 " " n, a[n]}' file
```

**Output**

```
2835:  OK BAD 1
2835:  OK OK 35
```

**Output desired**

```
2835:  BAD
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Again with the huge input files. Any reason not to give us an input file of, say, 5 lines of input to consider for this rather than 50 or whatever that is? Any time you need a scrollbar on your input or output there's a problem. Please try to create a [mcve] (note **Minimal**) when posting questions. Why should the output be `2835:  BAD` instead of `2835:  OK`? I mean what if you only had 2 lines of input, one with BAD in $2 andf the other with OK in $2 - how do you decide which line to print? Or is the word BAD in the input actually unrelated to the word BAD in the output (if so fix that)?

Comment: Ed, As i mentioned in the title of the post if the values in column 2 are not equal then print 2835:  BAD,  if all values are same print 2835: I have deleted some rows. And all always the rows will be more than 30, no < 30.

Comment: Can you see though how you've made it confusing by having the word BAD be one of the input values and yet it's unrelated to the output value BAD - the 2 being the same text is irrelevant and coincidental? Why not change that to some other text to remove the potential confusion? Thanks for removing most of your input lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any awk:

```
$ awk '!seen[$2]++{cnt++} END{print "2835:  " (cnt>1 ? "BAD" : "OK")}' file
2835:  BAD
```

or if the the first field of the output is related to your input values:

```
$ awk '{key=$1} !seen[$2]++{cnt++} END{print key "  " (cnt>1 ? "BAD" : "OK")}' file
2835:  BAD
```

and more efficiently:

```
$ awk '{key=$1} !seen[$2]++ && cnt++{exit} END{print key "  " (cnt>1 ? "BAD" : "OK")}' file
2835:  BAD
```

Comment: Ed, The option 3 is the best one to be used in my case, thanks

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -m 1 BAD file || grep -m 1 OK file
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the OP is asking for but I'm almost certain it's not to just grep the first of a set of hard-coded values. Not sure what you're thinking with this one...

Comment: Ed, what means OP? . as I mentioned in my question if all values are equal the output will be OK, if they are not equal the output will be BAD.

Comment: OP means Original Poster.

Answer (score 1):

For one file:

```
awk ‘NR == 1 { a = $1; b = $2 }
     $2 != b { print a, “BAD”; exit 0 }
     END     { if (NR) print a, “OK” }’ file
```

For multiple files (one line output per file):

```
awk ‘
    function f() {
        if (ok != “”)
            print a, ok
        ok = “OK”
    }
    FNR == 1 {
        f()
        a = $1
        b = $2
    }
    $2 != b {
        ok = “BAD”
    }
    END {
        f()
    }’ file0 file1
```